# ¿Hay alguna manera de pasar una regla de css dinámica de JS para que pueda ser añadida en React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy creando una animación `on scroll` de un svg pero con `react` y tengo la siguiente duda, ¿hay alguna manera de pasar esta regla de css dinámica de `js`:

```
line.style.strokeDasharray
```

para que pueda ser añadida en react?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.line = React.createRef();
    
  }
  
  componentDidMount = () => {
    let line = this.line.current;
    let lengthLine = line.getTotalLength();

    line.style.strokeDasharray = lengthLine; // Alli iria
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="header-previus">
          <h1>Scroll down to show the magic</h1>
        </div>
        <svg width="149" height="562" id="delgada-linea" viewBox="0 0 149 562" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path ref={this.line}  d="M1 1C25.6599 75.33 143.5 121 113.5 192.5C83.5 264 -22.5 320.5 18.5 378C59.5 435.5 185 495.5 137 560.5" stroke="black" strokeWidth="2"/>
        </svg>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Mi css:

```
.App
  & > .header-previus
    height: 800px
    width: 100%
    background: lightblue
    & > h1
      color: #fff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que estás combinando como se definen los estilos en `React` a como se definen en `css`. Cuando haces `line.style.strokeDasharray = lengthLine;` estas tratando de acceder a la propiedad `strokeDasharray` de la manera en la que `React` hace referencia a los estilos (sin guiones y con camelCase), pero tienes que recordar que al estar usando la referencia directa del `DOM` estás tratando de acceder al `css` en su formato real en el cuál el nombre de la propiedad sería `stroke-dasharray`.

Cómo tiene un guión tendrás que utilizar la notación de corchetes cuadrados para acceder a tu propiedad en el objeto, así:

```
 line.style["stroke-dasharray"] = lengthLine;
```

Quiero agregar que existen mejores maneras de hacer esto dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer en tu implementación y que si estás aprendiendo deberías de usar elementos funcionales y `hooks`.

Espero que esto sea de ayuda, suerte programando.

Cómo demostración de que el código funciona correctamente y se puede cambiar de manera dinámica la propiedad puedes cambiar el `componentDidMount` de tu código por este:

```
  componentDidMount = () => {
    let line = this.line.current;

    setInterval(()=>{
      line.style["stroke-dasharray"]++;
    }, 200);
  }
```

Verás como se cambia la propiedad de manera dinámica.

Comment: Hola @FranAcuna gracias por la ayuda aunque no me toma el estilo que hace que la linea desaparezca. Si por css directo. Es que estoy aprendiendo animacion con svg y me puse como meta una linea pero me complico eso con react.

Comment: No sé porque no hará eso, pero esta es la manera correcta de cambiar la propiedad, si le pones por ejemplo un 4 o un 2 en vez de `lengthLine` verás como se cambia la línea punteada. Voy a agregarte un código donde puedas comprobar que esto está pasando.

Comment: Mala mia estimado! me funciono el cache nose porque no me dejaba actualizar! gracias!! te ganaste tu estrellita! otra cosa.. hablabas de que existen mejores maneras, te refieres a librerias? es que esto que quiero hacer es mas especifico.

Comment: Me alegra que funcione! Me refiero a que por ejemplo estás usando componentes de React de clase, si tienes la libertad de usar lo que quieras deberías de usar componentes funcionales. ya que esto es lo que se usa actualmente (igual es importante saber de los dos). También si vas a cambiar esta propiedad en tu componente de manera dinámica, podrías guardar el valor con el cuál vas a cambiar la propiedad como estado en tu componente y utilizar  `useEffect` o algún evento para controlarla, así podrías no usar `ref` y usar el prop de style directamente sobre el componente.

Comment: buena, lo voy a intentar ... despues de mejorar la linea eso si porque ahora queda la parte de que aparecen circulos en ciertas partes de la lineas a medida que se va dibujando en el scroll, me tinca que debera tomar dinamicamente el largo al momento y poner un evento.